# Push notification not appearing in notification tray

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, push-notification

I am facing one unusual issue that my notification is not coming in notification tray. Though I am getting sound and begde count too. So there should not be any problem with provisioning profile. I am not able to find anything with googling.

I have tested this case when app is in background and killed.

I have checked in settings also for my application its banner is selected.I also try with alerts but alerts are not appearing.

Any idea about this issue?

```
NSDictionary *userInfo = [launchOptions objectForKey: UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
```

I am getting this `userInfo = nil`
Is this the issue notification not appearing in notification bar?

Comment: Did the user give permission to allow your app to be in the notification tray? Check it in the settings.

Comment: does notifications from other applications appear in Notification area ?

Comment: yes.Its allowed from settings.and notifications showing for other applications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got the issue and that was from server side. 
Might be one of the same case for others too..

```
aps =     {
   alert =         {
        dictioanry =             {
            key = value;
            key = value;
        };
    };
    badge = 1;
    sound = default;
};
```

Here I asked the php person to add `body` tag and I was able to get notifications in tray..

So for the people with same issue just check out if you are missing any key from the server side.

Comment: Yes you have mentioned a good point above. Also there is one more case in which push notifications does not come is if we exceeded the limit of characters in the text of the Push Notification. So for future you can make a note of this as well.

Comment: Yes this this also one important case for failing push notification

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using FCM Push Notif, might need to check wheter the payload has "notification" field there.
Here is the example of full payload working with FCM:

```
{ 
"registration_ids" : ["xx5MSpbpuUe6lgYhXTX-gs:APA91bFxKmDCTlE2WA_hl29XjiNK7A-qpdRBJaz-JddCsx5CAxxxxxxxxxxGcoO0-moOMqT2T59cExxxxxt-uMgLUQgg4t8jL3uuccka6psdBXVl26bx2HfnSbvKAxxxxxx-x_xxxxx_"],
"priority": "high",

"data" : {
    "app_link": "xyz://abc/def/123/456",
    "title": "Testing",
    "icon": "htt://abc/image.png",
},
"notification": {
    "body": "Notification body",
    "title": "Here is the title",
    "subtitle": "and this is subtitle",
    "sound" : true,
    "content_available": true,
    "mutable_content": true,
    "priority": "high",
    "badge": "1"
}
```

}